# I get "Call requires API level X (current min is Y)" even though I changed min to X

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to call this code:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

But I get `Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16)`

So I opened `build.gradle` and changed `minSdkVersion 16` to `minSdkVersion 21`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my_id"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
```

I also added:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="27"
/>
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml.

But it still shows the message `Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16)`

Comment: Validate merged manifest - maybe other module library override your minSdk settings. You can find merged manifest after build here: app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/{buildType}/AndroidManifest.xml. Otherwise just clear cache and reload AS.

Comment: Thanks! Thats indeed the case. But I clicked on `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` but the merged file does still contain `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16" ...`

Comment: Ok, I got a gradle error saying that minSdkVersion is not allowed to be in AndroidManifest. I removed it and invalidated cache / restart again.  Now the red underline and the message dissapeared from the call. Thx!

Comment: Ok, next step will be checking app/build/outputs/logs/ you can find how what values merger took.

Comment: I've composed answer from comments and suggestions, just in case someone else finds this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such issues you can do two things:

1. Android Studio gets better and better but gradle integration still causes some problems so just invalidate cache and reload AS (Invalidate Caches / Restart).
2. You can trace how `AndroidManifest.xml` is build - it's merged from manifests in every module. First check `app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/{buildType}/AndroidManifest.xml` - it's final manifest file that will be put in APK. If you find not expected values there, as next step find how it was merged - inspect: `app/build/outputs/logs/` reports. For example if you discover that some library require bigger minSdk, you can  override it in your app manifest:

   `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="2" tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>`

   and just make sure that older devices don't execute lib code that requires newer sdks.

Answer (score 0):

These steps should fix it:

1. Edit your `app/build.gradle` file to modify the `minSdkVersion`. Temporarily set it to 1 integer higher than what you want.
2. In the editor popup that appears saying `"Gradle files have changed since the last project sync..."`, press <kbd>**Sync Now**</kbd> . Alternatively, on the Toolbar at the far right ➔ Press the 'elephant + down arrow' icon, which has the tooltip **"Sync Project with Gradle Files"**

[image: Android Studio toolbar - Button: Sync Project with Gradle Files]

3. Android Studio ➔ Build ➔ Rebuild Project
4. Open a source file that used to show the false-positive warning of `"Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16)"`. The warning should be gone.
5. Repeat steps 1, 2, 3 and 4, but with the `minSdkVersion` set to the correct version.